# Selenium difference on windows / linux

Tags: selenium

I have a JUnit test that imports org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.

Specifically, I am using dragAndDrop, outlined [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#dragAndDrop%28org.openqa.selenium.WebElement,%20org.openqa.selenium.WebElement%29)

When I run the Junit test on my local machine (windows), it runs perfectly. However, when the same test is run on a Linux machine, the method does not work. Everything else in the test runs fine but the dragAndDrop method does not work.

A co-worker said that it might have something to do "XVFB" but could not elaborate much.

Any comments appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using Firefox on Linux? Native events are disabled by default for Firefox on Linux. Advanced Actions API need native events. Try enabling them and then check your test on linux like below,

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```